# Match numbers not preceded by string

Tags: python, regex

I'm analysing some very large log files using Python regex.
I need to substitute every number in the log file, except the numbers that are preceded by 'java:' (the log files are made by a java program).

This means that given we have a line saying:

> This is a bogus test line with limit=300 doing 53 rounds and the error is in (Abc.java:417) and some more

The numbers 300 and 53 should be replaced, but not 417.

I filter on a line basis, and it should be noted that not all lines contain `java:[number]`.

The closest I have gotten is `((?<!java:)[0-9]+)`

Comment: What have you tried ? Trying something is a process of learning, you should do it.

Comment: Look up **negative lookbehind assertions**. They're designed to do exactly what you're after.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally saved the question before I was done. Now it's updated. I have tried negative lookbehind, but have trouble making it not match any of the following numbers until a non-number character occurs.

Comment: Great! Thanks for editing in what you've tried. (Notice the upvotes you're getting :-) Now, would you explain why that didn't work? (What were the results you expected, but got instead?)

Comment: As I see it, my main issue is that it's only omitting the first number after the negative lookbehind. The rest are matched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably what's happening with

```
((?<!java:)[0-9]+)
```

is that, sure, the match at *this* point,

```
java:
     ^
```

fails, but then at _this point,

```
java:4
      ^
```

succeeds, because indeed, `ava:4` is not `java:`.

You'll just need to add one more negative lookbehind,

```
((?<!java:)(?<![0-9])[0-9]+)
           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

so that only "complete" numbers are considered.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I was looking for. I tried putting `[0-9]*` in the negative lookbehind to try to fool it (dunno what I was thinking, my brain is frying over this). 
Testing your solution now :)

Comment: @beruic - Actually, your strategy was intuitively correct. The problem with _that_ is probably that most regular expressions engines don't support _variable-width lookbehind assertions_, and the `*` certainly makes it "variable width."

Comment: @beruic - In short, it's just doing two tests. (1) Test that this point is not preceded by `java:`. (2) Test that this point is not preceded by a number (because if it is, then we know we're "in the middle" of a number, _i.e._ we've already checked for the `java:` when we were at the _beginning_ of the number, so don't re-test and raise a false match because of the `ava:4`). Not sure if that makes anything clearer though.

Comment: It does, provided that I understand correct that the second test is dependent upon the first?

Comment: @beruic - Side by side, you can think of assertions as being joined by `&&` operators. So, strictly speaking, the second test is _not_ dependent on the first, _i.e._ the expression cannot match any numbers following other numbers, regardless whether `java:` is there or not. It just happens so that this doesn't matter: you don't care about the `00` in `limit:300` nor the `3` in `53`. You're always going to look at numbers as complete strings of numbers.

Comment: @acheong87 Oh, that explains something: I substitute with `[#]`, and have no duplicates. This must be because the first test fails and the second one is omitted then. In that light, I guess that the second test is dependent upon the first.